# Why a space make failed the evaluation of a command in \bibliography

Tags: macros, bibliographies, robust-commands

I created a command containing a list of bib files separated by a comma and a space.
Then, I give this command to `\bibliography`, which produce no bibliography.

If I create the same list but only separated by comma (without space), the bibliography is produced.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \newcommand{\PathBaseBib}{./biblioA.bib, ./biblioB.bib} % this is not working
    %\newcommand{\PathBaseBib}{./biblioA.bib,./biblioB.bib} % this (without space) is working
    \usepackage{natbib}
        \bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
    \cite{Knuth81} \cite{Lamport94}

    \bibliography{\PathBaseBib}
\end{document}
```

So I would like to understand why this simple space make fail the command `\bibliogrpahy`.
And for esthetic reasons, I wonder if it is possible to correct this and so feed `\bibliography` with a command containing a list with spaces.

Comment: You shouldn't have to specify the extension `.bib` in the argument of `\bibliography`. What happens if you run `\newcommand{\PathBaseBib}{biblioA,biblioB}`?

Comment: From my tests, both are working / not working with spaces. But I admit that I never know when using or not use extensions. So `\newcommand{\PathBaseBib}{biblioA,biblioB}` will work since there is no space but `\newcommand{\PathBaseBib}{biblioA, biblioB}` will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `\bibdata`, which is written in the aux file, doesn't want spaces in its argument because of how BibTeX reads its input, the standard `\bibliography` command does `\zap@space`, but this fails if the argument is a macro.

You can fix this as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\bibliography}{\zap@space #1}{\expandafter\zap@space\expanded{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\PathBaseBib}{./biblioA, ./biblioB} % this is not working

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\cite{Knuth81} \cite{Lamport94}

\bibliography{\PathBaseBib}

\end{document}
```

This will be written in the `.aux` file:

```
\relax 
\bibstyle{plain}
\citation{Knuth81}
\citation{Lamport94}
\bibdata{./biblioA,./biblioB}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

and you see that the space has been removed.

Beware that adding `.bib` to the files is *not* allowed generally. Only MiKTeX allows it, but it shouldn't.